# Bootstrap font awesome slow page speed issue all.js

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome, pagespeed-insights

Page Speed Insight mobile indicates that i loose about 3.3 s on my website with font awesome (cf picture). I use a  bootstrap template as framework. I am beginner in Bootstrap. I would like to keep the icons (FB, etc...). I have 3 icons in "Services" and 2 in the "footer".
[www.myseosimple.com](https://myseosimple.com/)
[image]How can I reduce this delay (without delete them ) ?

Thx for your advices

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="Agence de référencement de sites web. Spécialistes du 
        positionnement sur Google. Vous souhaitez gagner en visibilité sur les moteurs de 
        recherche ?" />
        <meta name="author" content=" Eric Gavrel" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Qt8fm7x0wG1y1PupZ37uwCIc9_o- 
        cdj65cdd5DLcpsw" />
        <title>Agence de referencement site web Toulouse | myseosimple</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
         <!--
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
        family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         -->

        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-176459720-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-176459720-1');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">My Seo Simple</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
      href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
      href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
      href="#about">A propos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
      href="#team">Avis</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" 
      href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Masthead-->
        <header class="masthead">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="masthead-subheading"><h1 class="h2">Spécialistes du référencement de 
       sites web</h1></div>
                <div class="masthead-heading text-uppercase">Numéro 1 sur Google</div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" 
       href="mailto:seo31consulting@gmail.com">Nous contacter</a>
                <div class="container"><br>
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 1.3rem"> Le référencement naturel est 
       la solution qui permet à votre site web <br>d'apparaître dans les premiers résultats de 
       recherche Google.</p></div>
                
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Services-->
        <section class="page-section" id="services">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Audit SEO &amp; Web Design</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Création de sites web optimisés 
       pour le référencement</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-chart-bar fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h4 class="my-3">Audit SEO</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Nous vous proposons un audit détaillé de votre 
       site web: <strong>On-Page</strong>, <strong>Off-Page</strong>, 
       <strong>Technique</strong>. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h4 class="my-3">Responsive Design</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Nous créons des sites responsive qui s'adaptent à 
       toutes les surfaces: mobiles, tablettes, laptop.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-google fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                        <h4 class="my-3">Google first</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Google détient 92% du marché des moteurs de 
      recherche.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Portfolio Grid-->
        <section class="page-section bg-light" id="portfolio">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Portfolio</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">La création aux services de 
     tous</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" 
     href="#portfolioModal1">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus 
      fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img1.webp" 
      alt=" site meubles et décoration" title="site meubles et décoration"/>
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">E-commerce</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Meubles et 
       décoration</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" 
      href="#portfolioModal2">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img2.webp" alt="site esthetique" title="site web esthétique"/>
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">Esthétique</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Beauté &amp; SPA</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal3">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img3.webp" alt="site parfumerie" title="parfumerie" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">Parfumerie</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Senteurs d'antan</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal4">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img4.webp" alt="site relations publiques" title="site web relations publiques"/>
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">Communication</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Agence relations publiques</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal5">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img5.webp" alt=" site agence web marketing" title="agence web marketing" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">Web Marketing</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Communication digitale</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal6">
                                <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                </div>
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/img6.webp" alt="site evenement sportif" title="marathon" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-heading">Sport</div>
                                <div class="portfolio-caption-subheading text-muted">Marathon</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- About-->
        <section class="page-section" id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Notre histoire</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Tout voyage commence par un premier pas</h3>
                </div>
                <ul class="timeline">
                    <li>
                        <div class="timeline-image"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/1.webp" alt="agence seo toulouse" /></div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>2018-2019</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Des débuts prometteurs</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">En 2018, je décide de me lancer dans l'aventure de la création d'une <strong>agence web</strong> spécialisée dans l'accompagnement des <strong>petites entreprises</strong>: artisans, professions libérales, auto entrepreneurs.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                        <div class="timeline-image"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/2.webp" alt="agence web marketing Toulouse" /></div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>Mars 2020</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Une agence est née</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">Après plusieurs mois passés à peaufiner le projet, l'agence <strong>myseosimple </strong>voit le jour au printemps 2020 à Toulouse.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="timeline-image"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/3.webp" alt=" consultant seo Toulouse" /></div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>Decembre 2020</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">SEO &amp; covid 19</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">Des bouleversements importants ont eu lieu dans notre société. Le <strong>SEO</strong> est devenu une solution marketing incontournable pendant la <strong>crise covid 19</strong>.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                        <div class="timeline-image"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" src="assets/img/about/4.webp" alt="seo e-commerce" /></div>
                        <div class="timeline-panel">
                            <div class="timeline-heading">
                                <h4>Juillet 2021</h4>
                                <h4 class="subheading">Phase 2 Expansion</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-body"><p class="text-muted">Fort de nos premiers succès et de la statisfaction de nos clients, nous continuons notre phase d'expansion vers le <br><strong>e-commerce</strong>.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="timeline-inverted">
                        <div class="timeline-image">
                            <h4>
                                Avec
                                <br />
                                nous
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Team-->
        <section class="page-section bg-light" id="team">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Ce que disent nos clients</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Les avis de chacun sont précieux</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="assets/img/team/jyc.webp" alt="jean yves chouteau luthier" title="luthier guitare toulouse" />
                            <h4>Jean Yves Chouteau</h4>
                            <p class="text-muted">Luthier à Toulouse</p>
                            <p><em>"Une agence très compétente, professionnelle qui m'a apporté plein d'idées pour ma boutique de lutherie. Je suis très satisfait."</em></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="assets/img/portfolio/img2.webp" alt="formation nativo paris" title="formation nativo paris" />
                            <h4>Belle de nuit</h4>
                            <p class="text-muted">Produits de beauté </p>
                            <p><em> Nous avions des soucis avec le référencement de nos produits en ligne. Cette agence a répondu à nos attentes. Nos ventes sont reparties en hausse."</em></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="team-member">
                            <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="assets/img/portfolio/img4.webp" alt="seo et sea" />
                            <h4>Clémence Nandillon</h4>
                            <p class="text-muted">Relations publiques</p>
                            <p><em>"Excellente recommandation pour notre agence de commnunication. Nous avons apprécié le travail efficace de l'agence myseosimple."</em></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center"><p class="large text-muted">Que vous soyez artisans, professions indépendantes, le référencement naturel <br>peut vous apporter beaucoup en notoriété, en trafic.<br><strong>Plus de trafic, c'est plus de clients !</strong></p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Clients-->
<!--
        <div class="py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3">
                        <a href="#!"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="assets/img/logos/envato.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3">
                        <a href="#!"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="assets/img/logos/designmodo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3">
                        <a href="#!"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="assets/img/logos/themeforest.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3">
                        <a href="#!"><img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="assets/img/logos/creative-market.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
-->
<!-- Contact -->

 <section class="page-section" id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
                        <h2 class="mt-0" style="color: #fff">Restons en contact</h2>
                        <hr class="divider my-4" />
                        <p style="color: #E8E8EA">Prêt à vous lancer dans l'aventure, à démarrer un nouveau projet ? <br>Je réponds à toutes vos questions en 24h.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto text-center mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone fa-3x mb-3 text-muted"></i>
                        <div><a href="tel:+33766279110">07-66-27-91-10</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto text-center">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x mb-3 text-muted"></i>
                        <!-- Make sure to change the email address in BOTH the anchor text and the link target below!-->
                        <a class="d-block" href="mailto:seo31consulting@gmail.com">myseosimple@gmail.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
<!-- End of contact -->
       
<!-- Footer-->
        <footer class="footer py-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-lg-left">Copyright © msyseosimple 2020<br>37 rue Pierre Paul Riquet, Bat A <br>31000 Toulouse<br><a href="tel:+33766279110">0766279110</a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 my-3 my-lg-0">
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://www.facebook.com/Myseosimple-108291600992354"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-social mx-2" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/eric-gavrel-294992169/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-lg-right">
                        <a class="mr-3" href="mentions-legales.html">Mentions légales</a>
                    </div>             
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

<!--        End of Footer        -->

        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Third party plugin JS-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Contact form JS-->
        <script src="assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/mail/contact_me.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

For the JavaScript add `defer` or `async` as an attribute on the script tag.

As you stated you are beginner use the `defer` attribute as this tells the browser not to block rendering, but it just delays the script(s) loading until after document ready (but keeps the order of the scripts, so if one relies on another nothing will break).

`async` on the other hand tells the browser not to block rendering, but this time it says "grab me all the JavaScript files as fast as possible". It does not care what order they load and run in so this can cause issues if not handled properly.

For example:
`<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>`

### CSS

For CSS it is a lot more complicated, you have to inline the styles that are required "above the fold" (the initial content seen on the page).

This [article is a good introduction to understanding critical CSS and how to inline it](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/)

### SVG - the better way

Loading the whole of font awesome for 5 icons is not a great idea due to the shear size and the minimum of 3 requests (plus latest versions of font-awesome output SVGs anyway so why not put them in manually if you only have a few).

A much better way is to use inline SVGs due to their size, accessibility and the fact they can be put directly within your HTML (so they don't delay loading and can be displayed the second your HTML is loaded and parsed).

This [article may be a good starting point on using SVGs](https://www.viget.com/articles/getting-started-with-inline-svg/)

In the following example for a YouTube icon there are a couple of things to take note of.

I am assuming you would use these icons within a hyperlink. As such you need to ensure that screen reader users and people who use assistive technology (people with disabilities) can access the information inside the link.

As such the SVG has a `<title>` which informs assistive technology what to read out (think of it like an `alt` attribute on an image).

Then we use `aria-labelledby="youtube-title"` to improve compatibility for screen reader users. Basically [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) points to the ID of an element on the page and says "please read the contents of this item to screen readers".

```css
.icon{
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://youtube.com">
<svg aria-labelledby="youtube-title" class="icon" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
    <title id="youtube-title">YouTube</title>
        <path fill="#666" d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z">
        </path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer and the time you spent to write. I couldn't expect better answer. You're Santa Claus  for me :) Have a nice holidays !

Comment: ho ho honestly that is such a nice thing to hear :-P hehe. Good luck in the project.